# Javascript event when Ribbon buttons container in opened

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to hide a part of page header when user starts working with ribbon.

So is there any way to get **JavaScript event when container in Ribbon is opened/closed** so that i could affect some other element on the page using jQuery. Properties of _ribbon object didn't show the such information..

*by container i mean* set of buttons, which appear after clicking on ribbon tabs, here's a screenshot: http://oi41.tinypic.com/bim0ec.jpg